# Simple script run via cronjob doesn't work but works from shell

Tags: cron, bash-scripting, cpanel

I am on shared hosting and I'm trying to schedule cronjob to run every now and then. Via cPanel I scheduled to execute my script but even though that according to my host support the cronjob runs, the script doesn't seem as doing anything. The cron job command I set via cPanel is:

```
/bin/sh /home1/myusername/public_html/somefolder/cronjob2.sh
```

and the `cronjob2.sh`

```
#!/bin/bash
/home1/myusername/public_html/somefolder/node_modules/forever/bin/forever stop 0
```

when via SSH I execute:

```
/home1/myusername/public_html/somefolder/cronjob2.sh
```

it stops forever process as needed. From cronjob doesn't do anything.

How can I get this working?

EDIT:

So I've tried:

```
/bin/sh /home1/username/public_html/somefolder/cronjob2.sh >> /tmp/mylog 2>&1
```

and `mylog` entries say:

```
/usr/bin/env: node: No such file or directory
```

It seems that forever needs to run node and this cannot be found. How would I possibly fix this?

Comment: It should do it, but I want to ask to you: does it stop forever process even if you execute the script with `/bin/sh /home1/myusername/public_html/somefolder/cronjob2.sh'?

Comment: if I execute script `/bin/sh /home1/myusername/public_html/somefolder/cronjob2.sh' it does work. I also updated my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may need to define your PATH and other environment variables at the start of your script. Type "set" to show their values in your current shell, then copy/paste whatever you need, adding lines until your script works.